# are test prediction of yolov7 according to resized image we input during training?

Tags: image-resizing, yolov7

I am trying to figure out is my yolov7 well trained by plotting the predicted bounding boxes and ground truth bounding boxes, so i am confused that are the predicted bounding boxes according to resized image ?

precision 0.9966
recall 0.9962
all the predicted bbox have confidence more than 0.85 but still after plotting the pred bbox it is shifted to the left